# Error while installing PixieDust on MacOS

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I use MacOs 10.14 and and I already have jupyter notebook and python 3 installed. I installed spark 2.4.4 through homebrew and everything looked good.
I installed Pixiedust via `pip` and when I try to install Jupiter Kernel `jupyter pixiedust install` I follow instructions:

1. First step:

   ```
   PIXIEDUST_HOME: /Users/USERNAME/pixiedust
   Keep y/n [y]? y
   ```
2. Second step: Please enter a `SPARK_HOME` location: "/Users/USERNAME/spark":

   ```
   Directory /Users/USERNAME/spark does not contain a valid SPARK install
   Download Spark y/n [y]? n` And I provide de spark path.
   ```

But at the end I received this error:

> Unable to find py4j in SPARK_HOME: /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.4